# How to get the lowest integer without using loops or sort lists C #

Tags: c#, min

I have a list with N elements of integer (stack) type and need to retrieve the lowest value, however I can not make loops or even sort the list using Linq .min (). I can not use this because it's a challenge.
The method to be implemented must be O (1).
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Here my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleStack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack<int> Stack = new Stack<int>();

            int sair = 0;
            string print = string.Empty;
            while (sair == 0)
            {
                showOptions();
                int ChooseUser = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (ChooseUser == 0)
                {
                    sair = 1;
                }
                else if (ChooseUser == 1)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to insert into the stack\n");
                    Stack.Push(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    Console.Clear();
                    ShowStack(Stack);
                    Console.WriteLine(print);
                }
                else if (ChooseUser == 2)
                {
                    Console.Clear();

                    if (Stack.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no number in the Stack to be removed!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Stack.Pop();
                        ShowStack(Stack);
                        Console.WriteLine(print);
                    }
                }
                else if (ChooseUser == 3)
                {
                    Console.Clear();

                    if (Stack.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There are no numbers in Stack!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int menorInteiro = Stack.Min(item => item); /* I cant make this */
                        Console.WriteLine("Whole lower stack: " + menorInteiro);
                    }
                }
                else if (ChooseUser == 4)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    ShowStack(Stack);
                    Console.WriteLine(print);
                }
            }
        }
        static public void showOptions() /* Method for displaying the screen options for the user */
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nChoose an Option:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Exit type 0");
            Console.WriteLine("Insert into Stack type 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Remove from Stack type 2");
            Console.WriteLine("View the smallest item in Stack type 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Show Stack type 4\n");
        }

        public static void ShowStack(Stack<int> Stack) /* Method for displaying stack items */
        {
            Console.Write("\n\t");

            if (Stack.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Object obj in Stack)
                    Console.Write(obj + "\n\t");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Stack Empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to keep track of the lowest number as it is entered by the user?

Comment: Don't use stack. Use SortedList.

Comment: This may be more on-topic on codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: At first You should specify what you are really trying to do. It seems to me, that you try to extend stack implementation in such a way that you can retrieve smallest number on the stack at any time in O(1). But it can be anything else. Your question is confused.

Comment: This is exactly what I need: "retrieve the smallest number on the stack at any time in O (1)"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me besides min or orderby that you do not want to use. I don't know if it will work for your code as well.

```
void Main()
{
 int val = 0;
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack.Push(4);
    stack.Push(2);
    stack.Push(1);  
    stack.Push(3);
    stack.Push(6);
    stack.Push(7);
    stack.Push(5);  
           stack.Aggregate((a,b)=>{
              if(val == 0){
                  val = (a > b) ? b : a;
                }
              else {
                  val = (a > b) ? ((b >= val) ? val : b) : ((a >= val) ? val : a);
              } 
              return val;
           });


           Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Comment: I'll test your suggestion.